# How to order records case-insensitively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In the `index` view of my controller I am trying to sort `projects` by name:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.order(:name)
  end

end
```

The problem is that this gives me all projects starting with uppercase letters first (in alphabetic order) and **then** all projects starting with lowercase letters.

Is there a way to order them all together without changing the database values?

Right now I am using SQLite but I might want to move to Postgres later.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work both in SQLite and PostgreSQL:

```
@projects = current_user.projects.order('LOWER(name)')
```